# Can not ping broadcast address on one machine on a LAN but cannot ping it from another machine on the LAN

Tags: networking

I am trying to ping the broadcast address on my LAN.

I am getting time out and from another machine on the same LAN I can ping the broadcast address `192.168.1.255`.

Why is this happening?
Operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: Please edit your question: What is the OS these systems are running on? What is the LAN exactly? Is this a home LAN created by a router? Or a school or corporate or some other more formal kind of LAN.

Comment: I have tested in my windows 7 and windows 10 machine, they all get time out response. I would think this is a normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast IP doesn't belong to some specific machine. As it stands from it's name it sends a broadcast packet to all the clients in the network segment or vlan.
So, pinging a broadcast IP is not similar to reaching some specific computer.

Many modern OS are now disabling response to the broadcast. They ignore them to avoid security issues.

x.x.x.255 is a broadcast address, you are sending a ping to every device on your local network and you will get a reply from every device. The ping command is only showing the first reply it gets, including your own PC. In the 1st case your own PC was the quickest to answer. In another case it wasn't and no response received because it's most probably blocked by firewall when another machine answered.
You would never know which exactly machine will answer the broadcast in each and every case.

If you use a packet sniffer (like Wireshark) you will be able to see all replies.

Summary:
It's not an issue that you don't get reply to broadcast on Windows 10 machine, this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer .
This may be true but we have software running that uses the broadcast ping to update the arp tables for phone equipment routing. The phone system is not able to get the updated network.